# VirtualHost mod_rewrite multiple domains same DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a VirtualHost with many ServerAlias domains defined.  Using mod rewrite in the VirtualHost, I would like the following to occur:

sub.abc.com changes to sub.abc.com/?client_id=ABC

sub.def.com changes to sub.def.com/?client_id=DEF

sub2.abc.com changes to sub2.abc.com/?client_id=GHI

[... and so on ...]

My current configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:8080>
  ServerName sub.abc.com
  ServerAlias sub.def.com sub2.abc.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/prod/

  [... some other things ...]

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.abc\.com
    RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/?$ login.php?client_id=ABC [NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.def\.com
    RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/?$ login.php?client_id=DEF [NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2\.abc\.com
    RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/?$ login.php?client_id=GHI [NC,L]
  </IfModule>   

</VirtualHost>
```

But this doesn't actually do the rewrite .. I am pretty sure my Cond or Rule is messed up (lol .. I guess that is pretty obvious).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion :

Let's say your domain name sub.abc.com is pointing to X ip address. Consider creating two additional records sub.def.com and sub2.abc.com  under the same ip address X.

 
This practice is called as [Shared Web Hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service)  
This way you can maintain separate configuration files for your three different domains.

So if a Client accesses sub2.abc.com - the configuration file for sub2.abc.com will come into picture and request will be served accordingly.

I hope this helps! Good Luck!